# How can I sort a Laravel Collection by both string length and alphabetically?

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, collections

I'm using a Laravel Collection and this is what I currently have. I can sort by imageName or string length but I can't figure out how to do both at the same time. Some help would be appreciated!

```
function sortCards($collection) {
    return $collection->sortBy(function($key) {
        return strlen($key->imageName);
    })
    ->values();
}
```

I've tried this too:

```
function sortCards($collection) {
    return $collection->sortBy(function($key) {
        return $key->imageName;
    })
    ->sortBy(function($key) {
        return strlen($key->imageName);
    })
    ->values();
}
```

When I do it this way it only sorts based on the last sorting method, so it is alphabetically unsorted.

For example if the image names are:

```
p1, p1a, p2, p2a, p3, p3a, p4, p4a
```

Expected results would be:

```
p1, p2, p3, p4, p1a, p2a, p3a, p4a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@The Shift Exchange is right, [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) does that. However it only takes an array as argument. And it can't be a multilevel array. [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) in combination with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag works much better.

First we need to get a list. An array with only the property you want to sort by. `array_multisort` will use this list to sort the full `$items` array.

```
function sortCards($collection){
    $items = $collection->all();
    $list = $collection->lists('imageName');

    array_multisort($list, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $items);

    return new Collection(array_values($items));;
}
```

### Edit

Since PHP's natural sort prioritizes the alphabetical order over the length and you need the opposite you have to do it yourself using `sort()` (under the hood [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) gets called)

```
function sortCards($collection){
    return $collection->sort(function($a, $b){
        $lengthA = strlen($a->imageName);
        $lengthB = strlen($b->imageName);
        $valueA = $a->imageName;
        $valueB = $b->imageName;

        if($lengthA == $lengthB){
            if($valueA == $valueB) return 0;
            return $valueA > $valueB ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return $lengthA > $lengthB ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still not sorting correctly. I'd like it to sort by imageName string length first and then sort alphabetically. For example if the image names are p1, p1a, p2, p2a, p3, p3a, p4, p4a I'd like it to sort as -> p1, p2, p3, p4, p1a, p2a, p3a, p4a.

Comment: Ah so length should be the first priority and alphabetical the second. Think you will need to do this manually. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Okay I've updated the question with the code for a "manual" sort. Take a look.

Answer (score -1):

What you are after is referred to as a natural sort. [PHP does provide this functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php), so you'll just need to incorporate it into your function.

I havent tried it - but something along these lines should work (or at least point you in the right direction):

```
function sortCards($collection) {
    return $collection->sortBy(function($collection) {
        return natsort($collection->imageName);
    })
```

edit: this might even work:

```
  function sortCards($collection) {
        return natsort($collection->imageName);
  }
```

Comment: First one gives me the error: natsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given. The second one won't work. Sorry, I had typos in my question which I have fixed.

Comment: I did try, return natsort($collection); but it says the collection is an object.